# Deleted answer, edited/discussion

Tags: support, moderation, deleted-answers

I had an answer deleted. I edited it. Has the edit been rejected? Or is that it now, I cannot post to the question?

I don't feel I made any statement that can't be fully referenced. How can I get feedback or discuss this.